# R package with code that only runs once (per installation)

Tags: r, analytics

I'd like to create an R package that, upon installation, displays contact information for the maintainer and ask the user for permission to count them in our list of installations. It would also be acceptable to have the code run the first time the user calls one of our functions, instead of immediately on installation. Either way, this message should only appear once ever (unless the user reinstalls / updates the package).

What I've considered:

- I know how to include a dataset for internal use, but I don't know how to change that data permanently.
- We could set an environment variable / app setting, but I don't know if there's a way to make that persist after the end of the session.
- Using an external service / server would be excessively heavyweight, and wouldn't allow users who don't want to be tracked to turn off the message.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: A lot of packages make use of `packageStartupMessage` in `.onAttach` functions. A short message is very reasonable for a useful package. `data.table`, as an example, advertises their data camp tutorials. Example here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/f78d7901dc5063a5157d37db4831e418ad021fe6/R/onAttach.R

Comment: Misses the (reasonable) point by OP to display _once and only once_.

Comment: If you do this *please* make it so there is a way that the question *never* appears because installations that require user interaction make me cry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code allows you to create a file in the package library:

```
activate_file = paste(system.file('extdata', package = 'your_package'), 'activated.txt', sep = '/')
file.exists(activate_file)
# FALSE
file.create(activate_file)

file.exists(activate_file)
# TRUE
```

Now you can check in `.onLoad` whether or not the `activated.txt` file exists. The first time you show the message, and then you create `activated.txt`, and in the next time the package is used the `onload` function sees the file and can skip the message.

Advantages:

- Persistent over sessions.
- Platform independent way that ensures the user has write privileges to create the file.

Disadvantages:

- Reinstall/upgrade wipes the `activated` file, thus showing the message again.

If this is not acceptable, you could try and find a persistent location, e.g. in the home drive to do this (e.g. `~/.your_package/activated.txt`). Then the challenge is to make this platform independent. Maybe look at `path.expand(~)` to get the current users home drive, not sure if this works on Windows.

Comment: But you cannot assume you can write there. It could be mounted read-only.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel True, then using the homedrive of the installer would be a better bet.

Comment: And I just added _Edit 2_ to my answer detailing that.  There is of course a package for it ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel R can do all, if not, download a package! And ofcourse the package is writte (partly) by Hadley. We all live in the Hadleyverse...

Comment: Yes, see `fortunes::fortune("Blomberg")` which contains the immortal _This is R. There is no if. Only how._

Comment: I very much do not live in either the Hadleyverse or the Tidyverse.  And my R is untidy enough to prove it.

Comment: I didn't know about fortunes. This is great! Can R also check my email?

Answer (score 5):

This can run more than once but only within a limited time window so perhaps it is good enough.

Add this code to your package and it will issue the message any time the package is loaded within 7 days of installation and thereafter it will not issue the message again until the package is updated.

It works by comparing the time the install files were created to the current time.  It does not require write permissions to any directory, only read, so it should work generally.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
   ctime <- file.info(find.package(pkgname, libname))$ctime
   if (difftime(Sys.time(), ctime, unit = "day") < 7)
      packageStartupMessage("This msg will go away one week after installing this package")
}
```

Comment: Nice, avoids storing state but ... misses the (reasonable) point by OP to display _once and only once_.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! In my case I'm comfortable assuming that the reader will install the package only at the time they're planning to use it, so I could use a very short timespan and thus avoid repeated displays.

Answer (score 4):

You may have to bite the bullet and store state information across sessions to show it *once and only once*.

Some packages which may help:

- [settings](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/settings/index.html) which retrieves user configuration settings
- [config](https://cran.r-project.org/package=config) which retrieves configuration information
- [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=httr) which access config info
- [registry](https://cran.r-project.org/package=registry) which offers a registry
- [pkgconfig](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pkgconfig) offers private configuration.

but I am not sure which one reads *and* writes.  Maybe the last one fits the bill.

*Edit:* Turns out that even [pkgconfig](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pkgconfig) does not persist values across sessions.  I have solved this problem with company-local code when I had control over directories or databases to write.  For public and portable code it is a little harder.  I still think there is a package out there that stores user-level config on all major OSs but I cannot for now remember the name.

*Edit 2:* With a nod to Gabor Csardi to refresh my memory, the [rappdirs](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rappdirs) solves the problem of *portably* supplying a config location per-user (with other tricks too, a port of a corresponding Python library).  Combine this with a simple cvs or rds file to store when (at all) you last showed the message and you can now show it *once* and exactly once.  Not even again after a package upgrade.